# Знаки конца строк и табуляций неожиданно модифицируются

Tags: svn

Мой текстовый редактор SciTE или SVN неожиданно вносят ченжи, как на картинке ниже.
[image: Пример автоматического изменения]

Какие настройки могут влиять на подобного рода поведение?

Comment: Похоже, что редактор решил использовать другие переносы строк. Ищите по словам Cr lf

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно задать значение специальной опции в User Options File:

```
strip.trailing.spaces=0
```